# How to calculate mean of every three values of a list

Tags: python, list, numpy, mean, chunks

I have a list:

```
first = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]
```

I want another list  with mean of three values and so the new list be:

```
new = [2,5,8,11,14,17]
```

There will be only 6 values in the new list as there are only 18 elements in the first.

I am looking for an elegant way to do this with a minimal number of steps for a large list.

Comment: will the number of elements in `first` always be divisible by the window size?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The average value of a list, in chunks of 100 items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53373362/the-average-value-of-a-list-in-chunks-of-100-items)

Comment: For NumPy: [Average every x numbers in NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41815361/7851470)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take a slice of `first` using for loop that iterates in 3 interval

```
import statistics

new = [statistics.mean(first[i:i + 3]) for i in range(0, len(first), 3)]
print(new) # [2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17]
```

Answer (score 8):

Using `numpy`, you can reshape your list of 18 elements into an array of shape `(6, 3)` and then take the mean over the rows

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(first)

>>> a.reshape(-1, 3)
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18],

>>> a.reshape(-1, 3).mean(axis=1)
array([ 2.,  5.,  8., 11., 14., 17.])
```

---

The use of `-1` in `np.reshape(-1, 3)` actually allows you to use this approach for any array whose size is a multiple of 3 and it will automatically size the first dimension appropriately

Answer (score 6):

Heres a solution using `pandas` with `groupby`:

```
import pandas as pd

ser = pd.Series(first)
ser.groupby(ser.index//3).mean()

0     2
1     5
2     8
3    11
4    14
5    17
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's another solution using [`statistics.mean()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) to get the mean of each chunk of every three numbers in the list.

```
>>> from statistics import mean
>>> first = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]
>>> [mean(x) for x in zip(*[iter(first)] * 3)]
[2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17]
```